# Curl and OpenSSL functionality across Windows and Android

Tags: delphi, pascal

I've been looking to expand my knowledge into Pascal; specifically in Delphi RAD Studio as it is pretty easy to cross-compile for Windows and Android.

Two of the tools I often use in C++ are curl.exe and openssl.exe, which are pretty easy system calls with popen, and reading back results.

I've found solutions on SO for calling and reading back from stdout both for POSIX and WIN environments, but it all seems so clunky and would result in if-defines to know what system the program is running on, to then call the relevant procedure on the OS as there doesn't look to be a single solution for both Android and Windows.

Is this really the best way?  Or am I better to just include/import pre-compiled .dll/.so in WIN/ANDROID and call the methods via the interface directly?

Comment: `curl.exe` and `openssl.exe` don't exist on Android.  So you are better off compiling the libcurl and openSSL libraries into your app.  Just note that Android stopped supporting OpenSSL in Android 6.0, so you will have to ship the OpenSSL binaries with your app. Same with libcurl, anyway.

Comment: Thanks Remy... when you say "compiling the libcurl and openSSL libraries into your app" I presume you mean including the library via "LoadLibrary" such as detailed on this page? https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Libraries_and_Packages_(Delphi)

Comment: That is one way. Another option is to compile the libraries yourself into (or find pre-compiled) C-compatible `.obj` object files and then link them into your executable via [`{$L filename}`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Link_object_file_(Delphi)) and then using their functions via [`external`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions_(Delphi)#External_Declarations) declarations (similar to how Indy does when static-linking ZLib).